# Controlling what cores get loaded when solr 5 starts/restarts

Tags: solr

I setup my solr instance to run the way I wanted. The service was restarted and all my setup was removed and 4 gettingstarted cores were loaded.

Can someone explain why this happened and what I can do to prevent it from happening again.  I would like the cores that I built to be persistent.

Thanks for your help

**Edit:** Looking over :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Moving+to+the+New+solr.xml+Format

I have the solr.xml setup exactly like the example.  I have the core.properties files setup properly.  I don't see how it is suppose to know to load the core I created.

**Edit2:** I found this documentation that states any core.properties files in the home folder will be used.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Cores+and+solr.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Solr 5, it sounds like you run */bin/solr restart* and got wrong collections. The reason to that would be that the restart command needs the same parameters as the start command, most importantly your *solr home* path.

Solr home is what you provided with **-s** parameter when you started your Solr the last time. If you did it instead by starting from an example, [this guide on solr home locations](http://blog.outerthoughts.com/2015/11/oh-solr-home-where-art-thou/) should help.

Comment: Unfortunately I think my problem is a bit deeper than that.  Are there files in the home directory that are suppose to be configured to start specific cores?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also to confirm, yes I am using Solr 5

Comment: Sorry for all the messages, please note the edits in primary post

Comment: Sorry for all the messages, you were correct, I wasn't declaring the home directory properly.